# PHP DirectoryIterator::getSize - how real size and size on disk?

Tags: php, filesystems

I'm using code like this on windows XAMPP server.

```
    $di = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir);
    $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
        $di,
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
    );
    $totalsize = 0;
    foreach($files as $a => $b) {
        $totalsize += $b->getSize();
    }
```

Size i get is same (0.1MB difference) as Size On Disk == 62MB
However, windows shows real size is 42MB

Is there a way to get "real size"? Also, is real size and size on disk different on linux partition types also?

Answer (score 0):

There will always be a difference between a file's real size and its 'size on disk'.  A disk is split up into blocks, or clusters, of fixed sizes. A file occupies one or more clusters, and a cluster can only be part of one file, so the on-disk size will be always a multiple of clusters.  All filesystems work this way.

I am not familiar with that specific iterator, but PHP provides access to the standard POSIX stat() function, which returns all the information you could want about a file, including its real size, number of allocated blocks, block size of the underlying filesystem, access times, etc.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php

Just pass it a filename and it returns an associative array of data.  The entry you would be interested in is the `size` entry for the real size, or the `blksize` × `blocks` for the on-disk size.

Another method would be to open the file (`fopen()`), `fseek()` to the end of the file, then `ftell()` the position you are at in the file.

Comment: I realize it. Each file is separted into parts equal to block size. If last part is smaller rest of block cannot be used by other file.
That part of how filesystem works I know.
Thank you for information about POSIX stat().
I'm however interested in DirectoryIterator itself. And what will script return me on Linux machines.

Comment: On Linux I get the same value for getSize() as I do for the size entry in the stat() array.